# issue with eclipse and layouts

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout, android-2.2-froyo

When i change something in layout folder (medium devices) and go back to layout-xlarge folder, Some values changes.

In other word, when i change a file in layout folder, other one in layout-xlarge folder changed too, there is a infinite cycling loop  and i cant set values for proper resolutions. How i can fix that? what is this?

For example this two changes:
in layout folder:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/atxt"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:gravity="left" android:textSize="35dp"/>
```

changed to:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/atxt"
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:gravity="left" android:textSize="35dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place all values ​​in the dimension.
For example **res/values/dimen.xml**:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <resources>
>     <dimen name="atxt_width">250dp</dimen>
> </resources>
> ```

**res/values-xlarge/dimen.xml**:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <resources>
>     <dimen name="atxt_width">410dp</dimen>
> </resources>
> ```

And set the layout.xml this **atxt_width** - variable:

> < AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/atxt"
>           android:layout_width="**@dimen/atxt_width**"
>           android:layout_height="57dp"
>           android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
>           android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:gravity="left" android:textSize="35dp"/>